# How to place Boxes side by side but below another in html/css

Tags: html, css, class

I want to make it so that TopBox is on the top while BottomLeft is below TopBox but to the left while BottomRight is below topbox but on the right so that the two share the space evenly below TopBox

CSS

```
.textbox {
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    outline: 0;
    height: 25px;
    display: block;
}

.textboxSquare {
    display: inline-block;
}

#TopBox {
    width: 300px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#BottomLeft {
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}

#BottomRight {
    height: 25px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="textbox" id="TopBox" type="text"></div>
<input class="textboxSquare" id="BottomLeft" type="text"> 
<input class="textboxSquare" id="BottomRight" type="text">
```

Comment: can u make a picture of your exact requirement..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ATidanob/1/edit?html,css,output ?

Answer (score 0):

your topbox has `width : 300px` but left and right padding made the total `width : 340px`.....you have not taken that into consideration for bottom-boxes

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/2gmWh/

```
#BottomLeft {
    height: 25px;
    width: 164px;
}

#BottomRight {
    height: 25px;
    width: 164px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

John Kurlak's solution seems to be what you want, here's a slightly more flexible version. 
You can change the width of container and the other boxes will scale to match:

http://jsbin.com/AqoXECeB/1/edit?html,css,output

Keep in mind that when you add padding or margin, you have to adjust sizes accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input class="textbox" id="TopBox" type="text" />
    <input class="textboxSquare" id="BottomLeft" type="text" /><input class="textboxSquare" id="BottomRight" type="text" /> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.textbox {
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    outline:0;
    height:25px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    width: 300px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#TopBox {
    width: 100%;
}

.textboxSquare {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:25px; 
    width: 50%;
}
```